# ext3 slowing down on writes on linux 2.6.18

Tags: linux, ext3

i'm running into a problem where writing to a file will cause a 5 to 15 second pause, this occurs only on writes. So far i have remounted the filesystem with data=writeback as an option, and set /sys/block/sdb/queue/max_sectors_kb to 64 to shorten the queue.

Are there any other things i can try to solve this ?

Comment: Need more information.  What sort of storage sub system?  Are we talking about a single 7200rpm SATA drive or a RAID10 of 16 15k SAS drives?  How full is the file system?

Answer (score 1):

Are you reading and writing a large number of files?

mount -o remount,noatime,nodiratime /mountpoint

Can also help if you don't need to know the file's last access time.

Which IO scheduler are you using?  Deadline/Anticipatory have some odd corner cases that will cause issues.  CFQ is generally pretty good, but, the others might be better suited depending on your application:  http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7564/2/

Are barriers enabled or disabled?  Some controllers support barriers, but write performance suffers.  mount -o remount,nobarrier /mountpoint   or possibly   mount -o remount,barrier=0 /mountpoint

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend upgrading to ext4, you can do this in-place and it does have better write performance.

If you're reading and writing to the FS at the same time, then mounting with data=journal will [improve performance dramatically](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-fs8.html).

The next thing to try is to tweak the bdflush paramater - to write dirty buffers more often.

You can check the disks you're writing to, if its a RAID array there could be problems with the drives; alternatively make sure the write cache is on.

Comment: While you can upgrade to EXT4 in place it's not the same as a new EXT4 file system.  As it will lack a number of the new features in EXT4 like extents which improves performance when dealing with large files and helps reduce fragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

Is your file system filled up. When file system space usage goes near 100% many file systems  (and ext3 is not the worst) become slower and slower.